# Nested radio buttons angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<label>Enter Zone:</label>
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.zone" value="A">A
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.zone" value="B">B
<br>
<label>Enter Manufacture Year:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.motorYear" placeholder="Enter Manufacture Year">
<br>
<label>Select Cubic Capacity: </label>
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.rate" value="3.191"> Upto 1000 CC
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.rate" value="3.059"> 1001 - 1500 CC
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.rate" value="3.343"> Over 1500 CC
<br>
<label>Basic Od:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.basicOd" placeholder="Basic OD">
```

In this code, the user selects one of the radio buttons in the zone. After one of the Radio button is checked then the user enters the manufacture year. After entering the manufacture year user selects the cubic capacity. 
Now I have to make a function in such a way that there are 18 values from which one will be selected and the result will be displayed in the ng-`model="vm.basicOd"` input. Now suppose if the user selects zone A then there are 9 options left. As soon as the user enters the manufacturing year then only 3 values are left and after the user check the last radio button then we get the final output. Can someone give me some idea of how to make the function for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [
{rate: 3.191, zone: "A"},
{rate: 3.192, zone: "A"},
{rate: 3.193, zone: "A"},
{rate: 2.194, zone: "B"},
{rate: 3.191, zone: "A"},
]
```

use ng-repeat="rate in list | filter:{zone:vm.zone}"